# Could not load package because of error 0xC001000A. Description: The specified package could not be loaded from the SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, sql-job

I have created a SQL job which runs a SSIS package that is pasted in D: drive of sql server and the config file in the same drive as well. When the job is triggered, it stops in the package execution step and the showing the below error.

Could not load package "\package_name" because of error 0xC001000A.  Description: The specified package could not be loaded from the SQL Server database.  Source:   Started:  4:00:45 AM  Finished: 4:00:46 AM  Elapsed:  0.374 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

Job properties:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwJ1N.jpg

Please explain the steps on how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error on a new SQL 2016 installation on a Dev box that just had a fresh OS installation of Windows 10.  The .dtsx package installed properly on the server, but when I tried to run the SQL job, it immediately failed with this error.

> Could not load package "\packagename" because of error 0xC001000A. 
>   Description: The specified package could not be loaded from the SQL
>   Server database.

After a bit of searching got me no where, I logged out of the server and logged back in with the credentials of the user that was configured to run the SQL Agent Service.  I re-imported the package to SQL Server and tested it again by running the job.  Bingo!  Everything worked normally.

Logged back out of the server and went back to my normal user account to try running the job and it worked fine!

It appears the user account that is configured to run the SQL Server Agent Service has to have logged in to the machine before you can start an SSIS package via a job.

Answer (score 1):

Just do 1 thing, connect to your integration service instance using ssms, then expand any msdb package. Now disconnect it from the SSMS . All ssis jobs will start running.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the SQL Server type: Integration Services, instead Database engine and there upload your package. And then again you create a job and start it.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't work, I've found that the package could be a 32 bit while your server is 64 bit. If so, use this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx

Comment: I have checked in project properties, _Run64BitRuntime_ is set to **true** also the server where the package is deployed is a 64-bit server. Any ideas please.

Comment: Okay then that's crossed off. Since you stored the package in D:, then it's probably not visible to it, as the error indicates, as SSIS Services isn't looking for the package there. There's a page here that explains it: http://www.sqlsafety.com/?p=268

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that the user has login access to the DB Server Security folder and datareader, datawriter permissions on the actual DB.